# Outdoor clothing and shoes brands that people wear in Iceland

Tags: clothing, iceland, winter, reykjavik, footwear

I was wondering, maybe for future purposes of visiting, what kind of outdoor clothing and shoes brands do people wear in Iceland, with focus on Reykjavik, during the whole year, but especially during the heavy winter! I am not interested in description of clothes Just for the notice, I am very cold sensitive person.

I will name few brands I know that make winter clothes and shoes, but I dont know if they are good enough and if Icelanders do actually wear it:

```
www.66north.com - authentic icelandic company
www.patagonia.ca
www.columbia.com
arcteryx.com
www.fjallraven.com
```

Comment: I changed the word 'brands' to kind and types, to avoid asking for opinions which the stack avoids. If it alters your meaning, you can edit and undo.

Comment: Thanks Dorothy, but I was really searching for brands, not types! Cheers!

Comment: @pnuts Thanks. I ve already read that article, however I am searching for specific brands of clothing.

Comment: Questions that are primarily opinion-based don't fit the format here, and are subject to being put on hold or closed.

Comment: @Dorothy I am sorry if I have broken any of the rules, in the case I will rephrase or delete the question. However I do not think that question is primarly opinion based. Type of clothing is probably connected to some brand and I would rather want ppl to give me few direct suggestions rather then describing composition of textile.

Comment: See [What clothes are necessary to visit Iceland in July?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25976/what-clothes-are-necessary-to-visit-iceland-in-july) for an example of a good question of this type. Asking about specific brands is not as useful as asking about what *kind* of clothing is appropriate.

Comment: @GregHewgill Hi Greg! Thanks for suggestion! However I am searching for specific companies that would provide all of the things mentioned in the post above. Some of this things, depending on a textile description, could not be good. Brand provide quality (sometimes), so thats what I am looking for, especially when it comes to winter clothes and shoes.

Answer (score 3):

The brand is not so important. The quality of the clothes is important. Of course, brand may be an indicator of quality. But just go to any normal sports/outdoor store in Iceland or your home country, and it's not too hard to judge the quality. If you go to a known sports/outdoor store in Reykjavik, for example, they're almost certainly not gonna sell low quality clothes. And the staff will be able to advise you. So stop worrying about the brand thing.

> I am very cold sensitive person.

I grew up in a quite cold country, and I've gone skiing, running, walking, playing, hiking, bicycling, etc. in the mountains there and in temperatures as cold as around -20 Celsius as a part of my childhood and youth. The single best tip I can give you is to wear wool. There is nothing like wool to keep you warm in a tough winter.

Here is a garment anyone living in a country like Iceland is familiar with. It's a tight fitting woolen garment called woolen long-johns. Any sports/outdoor store in any cold place will have it.

[image]

On top of this, you can wear normal clothes like pants and a winter jacket, etc. If you're still cold, put on another layer of wool, like a woolen sweater or even pants. You'll be ready to spend the whole day outdoors in Iceland.

Now, you may be thinking that wool next to your skin is itchy. It is, to some degree, but these days they have ways to treat the wool to make it less itchy. Also, you get used to it. I personally prefer a little bit of itching to being cold. If you cannot stand wool directly on your skin, however, there are synthetic alternatives. They look somewhat similar, but they are not actually wool. If doing this, compensate by wearing a thick woolen sweater and woolen pants on top of it.

Avoiding *wind* is also very important. Make sure your jacket is windproof. Windproof pants also exist.

*Rain* is another thing that can easily spoil your trip, so make sure you pack a solid raincoat and rain pants.

It's extremely important to keep your feet warm. Pack woolen socks. You can wear them directly on the skin or outside cotton socks if you prefer. Keep solid boots and make sure you have rain boots in case it gets wet. Few things are worse than wet feet.

Again, forget about the brands. Go directly to the sports/outdoor store and judge the quality there.